# Xdebug not working in centos7, port 9000 not working

Tags: centos, phpstorm, xdebug

I want to work with xdebug and PhpStorm, but xdebug port not listen in 9000.

How can I connect xdebug and PhpStorm?

Here is my `phpinfo()`.

```
PHP Version 5.5.24

System  Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.3.2
IDE Key phpStorm

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   phpStorm    phpStorm
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

In CentOS I run these commands:

```
[root@localhost xdebug-2.3.2]# netstat -nan | grep 9000
[root@localhost xdebug-2.3.2]#
```

but 9000 port not listen anything.

Why port not working? How can I fix this?

Comment: You have wrong understanding on ports and how it works. It's PhpStorm who needs to be listening on TCP 9000 port and xdebug just connects to client on that port. Read how it works first: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote . When read -- have a look at [these manuals](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm) -- in particular zero-config one.

Comment: wow @LazyOne Thanks a lot. I was read [link](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) and fix the problem. problem is xdebug.remote_host was wrong.